# Is it reliable to build desktop applications using web frameworks like Django?

Tags: django, database, server, cross-platform, desktop-application

Is it reliable to build desktop applications using web frameworks like Django?

The idea is to

- build the interface with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript
- use Python and Django for backend operations (calculations, storage and databases, etc)

and then run a server locally so that

- the interaction with the application is done through the browser
- other local devices can access the application by connecting to the device on which the server is running.

If that is possible and yields a reliable experience, then

- is the development server that comes with Django enough? If no, what servers are most suitable for our purpose? Is Nginx good for example?
- what database should be used? PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc? The app will need to store a large number of entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done this, but I can't see why not. You can use the Django REST Framework to create an API that your desktop application can talk to, in exactly the same way as you might with a JavaScript single page app.

But no, you should not use the dev server for production, even in a limited scenario like this. Apache/mod_wsgi or nginx/gunicorn are simple to set up and deploy.

For the database, it makes no difference. The Django core devs prefer postgres, but you should use whatever you are comfortable with.

Comment: I don't think OP wants to create desktop GUI. He wants to give the application - all of the code to the client so that they can run it on their computers and then access the app via a browser.

Comment: In fact, the point of all of this is to create a highly-customized GUI for my applications. Otherwise, a command-line Python program would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a webApp, so yes you can. Is not use the Django server, instead is very common use nginx for Django, and the best database is postgres for Django.

If you want to pass your project like a desktop app is better use Django server and SQLite for avoid create a new database server.

**Database**

I find this [answer](https://www.quora.com/Which-database-will-work-best-with-python-Django) explaining why is postgres better for Django

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. OP is asking if it's a good idea to distribute a web application to the clients so that they can run it locally. He's not asking if it's a good idea to serve a web application from his own computer.

Comment: well I think he wants to create a local server

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I edit my answer, tell me if that works

Comment: I still don't think this answers OP's question. And just so you know, I did not downvote, though.

Comment: I know, anyway I leave the message for the questioner